# I am getting error while converting html to pug in express js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am new to node.js. I am getting this error

> TypeError: /home/agile/projects/nodekb/views/index.pug:6
>       
> 4|   h1 #{title}
>       
> 5|   ul
>     
> > 6|   each article, i in articles
>       
> 7|     li= article.title
>
> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at eval (eval at wrap (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10),
>   :28:32)
>       at eval (eval at wrap (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10),
>   :47:4)
>       at template (eval at wrap (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10),
>   :58:136)
>       at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:427:38)
>       at Object.exports.renderFile (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:417:21)
>       at View.exports.__express [as engine] (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/pug/lib/index.js:464:11)
>       at View.render (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/agile/projects/nodekb/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)

here is my code,
views/index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 #{title}
  ul
    each article, i in articles
      li= article.title
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

//init app
const app = express();

//load  view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','pug');

//home route
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    let articles =[
        {
            id:1,
            title: 'Article 1',
            author: 'Bhakti Thakkar',
            body: 'This is article one'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            title: 'Article 2',
            author: 'Jeel Thakkar',
            body: 'This is article two'
        },
        {
            id:1,
            title: 'Article 3',
            author: 'Sonal Thakkar',
            body: 'This is article three'
        }
    ];
    res.render('index',{
        title:'Articles'
    });
});


//add route
app.get("/articles/add",function(req,res){
    res.render('add_article',{
        title:'Add Articles'
    })
});

//start server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server started on port 3000...');
});
```

views/layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Knowledgebase
    body   
        block content
        br
        hr
        footer
            p Copyright &copy; 2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you forgot to include the `articles` data in the `res.render` method.

To solve your issue, just change this code :

```
res.render('index',{
    title:'Articles'
});
```

To this one :

```
res.render('index',{
    title:'Articles',
    articles // Equivalent to `articles: articles`
});
```

This will provide the `articles` variable data to the templating engine.

Comment: Guess, it should be passed as `articles:articles`

Comment: @DavidR As I pointed out in the code comment, they are basically the same. If you don't specify the key, the variable name will be used as the key. I tested the exact same code on repl.it and it works nicely.